# Does the ArrayList return type method return the memory address of the ArrayList variable or a copy of it?

Tags: java, arraylist, reference, return-type

I have a piece of code:

```
public class Check {
    private ArrayList<Integer> diameters;       // Array of diameters

    public Check(int num) {
        diameters = new ArrayList<>(num);       // Create an ArrayList object.
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {          // Initialize the ArrayList.
            diameters.add(i, i + 1);
        }       
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getDiameters() {
        return new ArrayList<Integer>(diameters);
    }
}
```

Does the `getDiameters()` method return the memory address of diameters `ArrayList` (if so, do I need to copy each value individually like I did in the constructor) or does it return a copy of all the integers in the diameters `ArrayList`?

Does the return value of `getDiameters()` method and the variable `diameters` point to the same memory location?

Would the below return statement in the `getDiameters()` method be a valid statement without any compromise to security instead of writing "`return new ArrayList<Integer>(diameters);`"?

```
return diameters;
```

What are the security issues faced, if any, if I write the above statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Partly yes, but I want to understand those concepts in this particular scenario, question by question, since it is too confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `return diameters;` your whole `diameters` ArrayList would be mutable, as you provide a link to it directly. That means you can affect it size and content from outside.

When you do `new ArrayList<Integer>(diameters)` - you're providing a copy of ArrayList with the copied values (which are copied by a reference, so basically are the same objects as in original collection).

For primitive wrapper like Integer - it's safe, but if you were passing mutable Object within the collection - its change would change the original ArrayList content.

Simple example:

```
public class Arrayz {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
    array1.add(new Integer(1));
    array1.add(new Integer(2));
    List<Integer> array2 = new ArrayList<>(array1);
// you can't mutate Integer - it's immutable
    Integer first = array2.get(0); 
    System.out.println(array1);
    System.out.println(array2);

    List<Nom> array3 = new ArrayList<>();
    array3.add(new Nom(1));
    array3.add(new Nom(2));
    List<Nom> array4 = new ArrayList<>(array3);
    Nom third = array4.get(0);
// Nom is muttable - this will affect initial data as the Object itself mutated
    third.a = 88; 
// this will not - you replaced the Object in copied array only
    array4.set(1, new Nom(33)); 
    System.out.println(array3);
    System.out.println(array4);
  }
}

public class Nom {
  public int a;
  Nom(int a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "" +a;
  }
}
//////////// output:
[1, 2] // array1
[1, 2] // array2
[88, 2] // array3
[88, 33] // array4
```

Generally to protect everything you need to pass an immutable collection with immutable objects.
First can be achieved by using `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.of` for example.

Answer (score 3):

For objects, Java passes the reference to the object, so the method will not return a deep copy of the list.

As for security issues, this means that if a user manipulates the object returned by `return diameters`, these changes will also affect the object referenced by the `Check` object since they are the same object, which might be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getDiameters()
{
    return new ArrayList<Integer>(diameters);
}
```

Creates a new ArrayList of Integer, let's quote this from the docs:

> public ArrayList(Collection c)
>
> Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection,
>   in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.
>
> Parameters:
>       c - the collection whose elements are to be placed into this list Throws:
>       NullPointerException - if the specified collection is null

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-

Now, you have passed a `Collection` to the constructor, which, on its turn yields an ArrayList, which is similar, but not the same to your data member. It's not recommended to do this if you do not have a very good reason to do so, because diameters already contains the elements you have.

As about security, the only concern of security that I see is that the code using the diameters would have write operation privileges on the actual `ArrayList`. If you intend to prevent that, then don't return the actual `ArrayList`. You can `clone` it or create another `ArrayList` (as you did), or you can (and this is the most elegant solution in my opinion) call [unmodifiableList](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-unmodifiablelist-method-in-java-with-examples/) in order to return a readonly version of your `Collection`.

Answer (score 1):

The getDiameters() will return the address memory of the new created ArrayList. They don't point to the same address memory. it will copy the diameters elements to the new ArrayList. If you have many threads use the Arraylist, for security you can use:
 `Collections.synchronizedList(list);`